# OpenCL inconsistent reduce step depending on number of work groups

Tags: c, opencl

I run a simple OpenCL kernel with work groups of size 2. The kernel stores global IDs mod 2 in result array, and for each thread with index 0, stores the sum of the group's result array in the reduce array. The numbers do not match up when returned to C code, before the last 20 elements or so. What's going on?

OpenCL Kernel:

```
__kernel void hello (__global long* reduceBuffer, __global long* result, local long* sum) {
    int id = get_global_id(0);
    int tnum = get_local_id(0);
    int wgNum = get_group_id(0);
    int numItems = get_group_id(0);
    result[id] = id % 2;
    sum[tnum] = result[id];
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    if (tnum == 0) reduceBuffer[wgNum] = sum[0] + sum[1];
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
}
```

C Code:

```
int main() {
    size_t numElements = 128;
    size_t workGroupSize = 2;
    // OpenCL preamble with lots of buffer initialization

    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel (command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &numElements, &workGroupSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
    // read result from write buffers
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements/workGroupSize; i++) {
        printf("%d. %ld %ld\n", i, reduceArr[i], resultArr[2 * i] + resultArr[2 * i + 1]);
    }
    // free everything
    return 0;
```

}

Output:

> 1. 0 1
> 2. 0 1
> 3. 0 1
> 4. 0 1
> 5. 0 1
> 6. 0 1
> 7. 0 1
> 8. 0 1
> 9. 0 1
> 10. 0 1
> 11. 0 1
> 12. 0 1
> 13. 0 1
> 14. 0 1
> 15. 0 1
> 16. 0 1
> 17. 0 1
> 18. 0 1
> 19. 0 1
> 20. 0 1
> 21. 0 1
> 22. 0 1
> 23. 0 1
> 24. 0 1
> 25. 0 1
> 26. 0 1
> 27. 0 1
> 28. 0 1
> 29. 0 1
> 30. 0 1
> 31. 0 1
> 32. 0 1
> 33. 0 1
> 34. 0 1
> 35. 0 1
> 36. 0 1
> 37. 0 1
> 38. 0 1
> 39. 0 1
> 40. 0 1
> 41. 0 1
> 42. 0 1
> 43. 0 1
> 44. 0 1
> 45. 1  1
> 46. 1  1
> 47. 1  1
> 48. 1  1
> 49. 1  1
> 50. 1  1
> 51. 1  1
> 52. 1  1
> 53. 1  1
> 54. 1  1
> 55. 1  1
> 56. 1  1
> 57. 1  1
> 58. 1  1
> 59. 1  1
> 60. 1  1
> 61. 1  1
> 62. 1  1
> 63. 1  1
> 64. 1  1

Comment: Sorry, mistyped. Fixed in edit.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the kernel. Please include the rest of the host code (buffer init and reading from device), it's likely where the problem is. BTW, you don't need the global memory barriers, since each thread is accessing only it's own global memory locations.